# Printing subsets of a set with sum equals to k

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, subset-sum

Dynamic programming provides a very elegant way of solving subset sum problem. Subset Sum Problem: Find if a subset exist with sum = k.

But I am not able to see how can we print all the subsets with sum = k. Any pointers on how to modify the following dynamic programming based function which simply checks and returns true if a required subset exists. Kindly refer [HERE](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/dynamic-programming-subset-sum-problem/) for more details.

```
// Returns true if there is a subset of set[] with sun equal to given sum
bool isSubsetSum(int set[], int n, int sum)
{
    // The value of subset[i][j] will be true if there is a subset of set[0..j-1]
    //  with sum equal to i
    bool subset[sum+1][n+1];

    // If sum is 0, then answer is true
    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++)
      subset[0][i] = true;

    // If sum is not 0 and set is empty, then answer is false
    for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
      subset[i][0] = false;

     // Fill the subset table in botton up manner
     for (int i = 1; i <= sum; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
       {
         subset[i][j] = subset[i][j-1];
         if (i >= set[j-1])
           subset[i][j] = subset[i][j] || subset[i - set[j-1]][j-1];
       }
     }

    /* // uncomment this code to print table
     for (int i = 0; i <= sum; i++)
     {
       for (int j = 0; j <= n; j++)
          printf ("%4d", subset[i][j]);
       printf("\n");
     } */

     return subset[sum][n];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that a subset array already exists.

We can write a recursive function to print all subsets: generate(sum, prefixLength). It prints all subsets of a prefix with prefixLength elements that sum up to the sum. Inside, we need to check two things: if subset[sum - set[prefixLength]][prefixLength - 1] is true, we should generate all subsets for (sum - set[prefixLength], prefixLength - 1), append the current element to each of them and return the result. If subset[sum][prefixLength - 1] is true, we should return the result of generating all sets for (sum, prefixLength - 1). Sometimes both of this options are possible(in this case we need to return a union of the first and the second option). The answer is generate(sum, n).